# "Can't find variable" when sending string from java to javascript.

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So i am trying to implement google maps in my desktop application written in java.
This turned out to be a more difficult task than i imagined, especially with my lack of skills. 
I have never submitted a question here before but i will try to do it the way i've seen it done when researching.

This is my java class:

```
package GUI;

import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXGoogleMaps extends Application {

    private Scene scene;
    MyBrowser myBrowser;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("SHEEPTRACKER3000");
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
        scene = new Scene(myBrowser, 400, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    static class MyBrowser extends Region {
        HBox toolbar;

        static WebView webView = new WebView();
        static WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        public MyBrowser() {

            final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource(
                    "GoogleMapsV3.html");
            webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
            webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            getChildren().add(webView);

            webEngine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(WebEvent<String> arg0) {

                    System.out.println("We are here");
                    webEngine
                            .executeScript("document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'the new text';");
                    webEngine.executeScript("document.setNewMarker()");
                    webEngine
                            .executeScript("document.setNewMarkerWithParameters(nAME-63.44-10.39)");
                    // webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
                    // getChildren().add(webView);

                }

            });

        }
    }
}
```

And here is my html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAGiYaSPuB9Mx2t37gy9yhUR_QOUwdTWE0&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(63.43,10.39)
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myCenter,
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
            };

         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        var tilesloaded=true;
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function(){
            if(tilesloaded ==true){
             window.alert();
             tilesloaded=false;
            }
        });
      }
     document.setNewMarker = function setNewMarker(){
         var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
              position:new google.maps.LatLng(63.43,10.39),
              icon:'sheep1.png',
              map:map,
              });

     }
     document.setNewMarkerWithParameters = function setNewMarkerWithParameters(info){
         var array = info.split('-');
         var a = array[0], b = array[1], c = array[2];
         var lat = parseFloat(b);
         var longi = parseFloat(c);
         var name = parseString(a);
         var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
              position:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,longi),
              icon:'sheep1.png',
              map:map,
              });

     }
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1 id="test"> Does dis work?</h1>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px; height:300px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have been at this point for a while now, and the project deadline at school is closing in.
I get the error message "Can't find variable 'name'" and i don't understand what that means. To put this in context i am trying to make a function in java where i iterate over an array on the form [name-lat-long] and add markers to the map. However i can't get there as i get the error. The name variable is not used yet, as i am trying to make this part of the code working before I go further. But later I want to be able to click on the marker and find the name of the object at that location.
Any feedback at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: *Where* do you "get the error message"? In your Java code? The Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
webEngine
    .executeScript("document.setNewMarkerWithParameters(nAME-63.44-10.39)");
```

...you'e telling the engine to execute the `document.setNewMarkerWithParameters` function, passing in the result of this expression:

```
nAME
- 63.44
- 10.39
```

E.g., the variable `nAME` minus those two floating point numbers. I'm guessing you haven't defined the variable `nAME` anywhere.

But in your function, it looks like you're expecting that to be a string. If so:

```
webEngine
    .executeScript("document.setNewMarkerWithParameters('nAME-63.44-10.39')");
// Note the quotes -------------------------------------^----------------^
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the problem for me :) It's the smallest things that get you :P

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to replace

```
var name = parseString(a);
```

with

```
var name = a;
```

split returns a string anyway and as far as i know parseString doesn't exsits in java script (if you need use toString())

I acutally was able to run the code like that (using T.J. Crowder presented solution and removing the parseString)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, i was in fact aware,i had just forgotten to remove it :)